# Work on list index lua

Tags: lua

I just started using lua to configure a program and i bumped into this problem:

I have a list of lists like
    t = {
    {2,3,4}
    {5,6,7}
    }

And I want to look if the list t contains a certain element, and if it does I need to acess all the elements in the sublist that contain that element

like

```
if 2 in t then
"get all elements in sublist containing 2 and add them"
```

So if i look for two i need to get back the result 2+2+3=7
My list won't have any repeated numbers.

Comment: You mean `2+3+4 = 9`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing this:

```
local function list_sum(list)
    assert(list)

    local tmp_sum = 0

    for _, value in ipairs(list) do --iterate provided list and sum all values
        tmp_sum = tmp_sum + value
    end

    return tmp_sum
end

local function sublist_sum_containing(list, search_for)
    assert(list)
    assert(search_for)

    local ret_val = 0

    for _, tmp_sublist in ipairs(list) do  --iterate list
        for _, value in ipairs(tmp_sublist) do --iterate each sublist
            if value == search_for then --look for value
                -- OMG, we've just found sublist we were looking for!
                ret_val = list_sum(tmp_sublist) --sum exact sublist values.

                return ret_val --return sum and exit nested loops
            end
        end
    end

    return ret_val --zero. (no sublist found)
end
```

You might consider using recursion with deeper set of sub_lists.

Comment: Won´t this itterate over the list and sum only the values that match?

Comment: It would iterate each sublist looking for `search_for`. If that value found, it would iterate that exact sublist again summing all of it's values.

Comment: I applied this to my code and i have this:

`for i, quests in ipairs(specialquests) do
  result = 0
  for j, reward in ipairs(quests) do
   result = result + reward
   if reward == prize then
                           if result == -j then
                              (stuff)
                           end
                        end
                 end
end`

prize is the element im looking for, is there anbything wrong with this?

Comment: @user3508170 this should work. Only if I were You, I'd change `result = 0` to `local result = 0`, not to screw with some other defined/reused `result`. Also, separating huge blob of code into separated functions is considered to be a better practice. Also, You to to decide, if it work calculating sum of all sublists. I'd prefer reiterating correct one.

Comment: @Kamiccolo I don't think you should return in the middle of the loop since other  sublists could contain the prize item yet they would not be summed up. Rather, you want to do `ret_val = ret_val + list_sum...` without return.

Comment: @Schollii: quote: `list won't have any repeated numbers`. Just following the original question :} Also, that `return` in the middle of the `loop` was edit :}